# Error passing build number - Azure devops gradle task

Tags: android, azure, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to execute the below task in **Azure devops**:

```
- task: Gradle@3
displayName: 'Build Task'
continueOnError: false
inputs:
  tasks: assembledevelopDebug -PversionCode=$(Build.BuildNumber) -PdisablePreDex --no-daemon
  publishJUnitResults: false
```

I get the below error. Can someone please tell if there is anything wrong the way in which I am passing the build number **-PversionCode=$(Build.BuildNumber)** .

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> For input string: "20220804.6"

Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
* Try:
    at ExecState._setResult (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.205.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:944:25)
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.205.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:927:18)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.205.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:840:19)
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 23s
##[error]Code analysis failed. Gradle exit code: -1. Error: Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build Task
```

Please note, this is how I do the same in gitlab pipeline and it works without issues **assembledevelopDebug -PversionCode=%CI_BUILD_ID% -PdisablePreDex --no-daemon**

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out; I can pass only Integer value for PversionCode. Changing $(Build.BuildNumber) to $(Build.BuildId) will give an incremental unique Integer and resolves the error.